# Update to Wordpress child theme function.php breaks site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a child theme on my wordpress site, with a modified function.php as below

```
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
// AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_locale_css' ) ):
 function chld_thm_cfg_locale_css( $uri ){
 if ( empty( $uri ) && is_rtl() && file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/rtl.css' ) )
 $uri = get_template_directory_uri() . '/rtl.css';
 return $uri;
 }
endif;
add_filter( 'locale_stylesheet_uri', 'chld_thm_cfg_locale_css' );

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
 function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'fil-theme-flaticon','fil-theme-font-awesome','fil-theme-icomoon','fil-theme-pe-icon-7-stroke','fil-theme-simple','fil-theme-stroke','woocommerce-general' ) );
 }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 10 );

?>

// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
```

However if I change it to the the below, adding some of the code that I had originally added to the main theme function.php I get a critial error when going to the checkout page, presumably because it is trying to call one of the functions.

```
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
// AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_locale_css' ) ):
 function chld_thm_cfg_locale_css( $uri ){
 if ( empty( $uri ) && is_rtl() && file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/rtl.css' ) )
 $uri = get_template_directory_uri() . '/rtl.css';
 return $uri;
 }
endif;
add_filter( 'locale_stylesheet_uri', 'chld_thm_cfg_locale_css' );

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
 function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'fil-theme-flaticon','fil-theme-font-awesome','fil-theme-icomoon','fil-theme-pe-icon-7-stroke','fil-theme-simple','fil-theme-stroke','woocommerce-general' ) );
 }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 10 );

add_filter( 'wc_session_use_secure_cookie', '__return_true' );


add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_contents', 'checkout_message');

function checkout_message() {
echo '<div class="checkout_message"><h4 style="font-size: 20px;color: #ff0000;">
<p>Please be aware due to Covid-19 shipping times can be impacted.</p>
</h4>
</div>'; }

wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js';, false, null);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');


?>

// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
```

I thought that will a child theme the function.php file from the main theme would be overwritten.  This does not seem to be the case as the message I tried to add to the child theme function.php is still displayed.  The other code that is only in the child theme function.php seems to be working as well.

Any idea how I can move the custom code that I want to add from the main theme function.php to the  child theme?  I want to avoid loosing these if the theme is updated.

Comment: Silly question, did you take them out of the parent theme?

Comment: Mmm, I think so, but I'll have to check when at my PC tonight.  Nothing is a silly question when it comes to me and wordpress!

Comment: That will throw an error since the function was already declared.

Comment: I'd also remove ?>

// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
 at the end. You don't need to close PHP and it can actually cause errors depending on server config.

Comment: Sorry for delay getting back to this.  I did have one of the functions declared in both files so removing it fixed it.  If you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks will update with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to remove it from the parent theme or wrap it in

```
if(!function_exists('')) {
}
```